# When asking a third person's willingness or asking a third person to do sth - is "would" more polite?

Tags: modal-verbs

A friend and I have decided to go on a picnic this weekend.

Can I use "would" to ask about a third person's willingness? Does "would" sound more polite than "will"?

**Example 1**

> **Would** David go to the picnic with us?

**Example 2**

> **Will** David go to the picnic with us?

How about when making requests?

**Example 3**

> **Would** David go buy dinner for us?

**Example 4**

> **Will** David go buy dinner for us?

Comment: A suggestion to invite another person could be expressed as "Would David _like to_ go with us?"

Answer (score 1):

In your examples, when you use **would**, you introduce doubt or uncertainty about **your** participation, not just David's. When you use **will**, you're limiting the doubt or uncertainty to David.

> Will David go to the picnic with us?
>
> This implies that you are going to the picnic. The uncertainty is with David.

> Would David go to the picnic with us?
>
> This suggests only that you are considering going to the picnic. Your decision might depend on whether David goes, or you could make an independent decision. Using **would** makes the entire activity uncertain.

Similarly:

> Will David go buy dinner for us?
>
> This implies that you are going to have dinner, whether or not David buys it.

> Would David go buy dinner for us?
>
> This suggests that you might not have dinner -- even if David agrees to buy. The use of **would** introduces doubt or uncertainty about the entire activity.